# Replace new line character between two strings

Tags: perl

I have problem and see your answer in one of questions suiting with one exception

Here is what i am trying to achieve
\n (new line character) has to be replaced with blank when \n is between two `\"` strings, but with an exception that if I find `|` before another `\"` nothing should happen.

Below are my input\output examples

```
Input 1
test \" data
get this line\" in above line

Output 1
test \" dataget this line\" in above line

Input2
test \" data
keep| this line\" here

Output 2
test \" data
keep| this line\" here
```

for which if i am running the below command that is almost good for Input1 but not turning up right for Input2

```
perl -pe 's/\n(?=(?:(?!\\"|\\").)*(\\"|\n|))/\1/g' input1.txt
test \" dataget this line\" in above line[sh]$

perl -pe 's/\n(?=(?:(?!\\"|\\").)*(\\"|\n|))/\1/g' input2.txt
test \" dataget this line\" in above line[sh]$
```

In both Inputs above, after "data" there is a carriage return ie, the "data" followed text is in next line but in this post i am not able to see it in next line. 
Please help tweak this command.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below Perl one-liner.

```
perl -00pe 's/(\\"(?:(?!\\"|\|).)*)\n((?:(?!\\"|\|).)*\\")/\1\2/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
test \" data
get this line\" in above line

test \" data
keep| this line\" here
$ perl -00pe 's/(\\"(?:(?!\\"|\|).)*)\n((?:(?!\\"|\|).)*\\")/\1\2/g' file
test \" dataget this line\" in above line

test \" data
keep| this line\" here
```

**Explanation:**

```
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \\                       '\'
  "                        '"'
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                           times):
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
      \\                       '\'
      "                        '"'
     |                        OR
      \|                       '|'
    )                        end of look-ahead
    .                        any character except \n
  )*                       end of grouping
)                        end of \1
\n                       '\n' (newline)
(                        group and capture to \2:
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                           times):
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
      \\                       '\'
      "                        '"'
     |                        OR
      \|                       '|'
    )                        end of look-ahead
    .                        any character except \n
  )*                       end of grouping
  \\                       '\'
  "                        '"'
)                        end of \2
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and time Avinash.
The code is working as expected but my depiction of problem truned much simpler than the actual problem.
Problem: 
I have a file which has ~5Million of rows with 280MB Size & 20 Columns ( | delimiter)
Some of the data in a row got splitted into "N" number of rows due to some unkown reason from source which has to brought in a single row.

Please see the example below which is a row that has split into multiple rows:

Comment: could you ask it as another question?